# JOIN from tables evaluating results from one of them

Tags: mysql

I have three tables to join, one of them with one-to several values.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/605ce1)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1  (`id` int, `name` varchar(3));

INSERT INTO Table1   (`id`, `name`)
VALUES   (1, 'A'),  (2, 'B'),   (3, 'C');


CREATE TABLE Table2   (`id` int, `status` int, `date` varchar(9));

INSERT INTO Table2  (`id`, `status`, `date`)
VALUES   (1, 1, '''.11..'''),  (1, 2, '''.12..'''),   (1, 3, '''.13..'''),
         (2, 3, '''.23..'''),  (3, 1, '''.31..'''),   (3, 3, '''.33..''')
;


CREATE TABLE Table3  (`id` int, `value` int);

INSERT INTO Table3   (`id`, `value`)
VALUES     (1, 34),  (2, 22),  (3, 17);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from table1

| id | name |
|----|------|
|  1 |    A |
|  2 |    B |
|  3 |    C |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from table2;

| id | status |    date |
|----|--------|---------|
|  1 |      1 | '.11..' |
|  1 |      2 | '.12..' |
|  1 |      3 | '.13..' |
|  2 |      3 | '.23..' |
|  3 |      1 | '.31..' |
|  3 |      3 | '.33..' |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select * from table3

| id | value |
|----|-------|
|  1 |    34 |
|  2 |    22 |
|  3 |    17 |
```

I need query that returns for each id:

```
   TABLE1.name, TABLE2.status, TABLE2.date, TABLE3.value
```

with this condition:

- If TABLE2.status =1 exists then return ONLY that line of TABLE2
- Else if TABLE2.status =1 does not exists then look for status =2 and return ONLY that line of TABLE2
- If no one of those values are present in TABLE2 then skip that id from results

EDIT: TABLE2 has an UNIQUE key for id,status so there can be only one id=1 status=1

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a UNIQUE constraint on `table2 (id, status)`?  Can there be *more than one* row in `table2` that satisfies the condition  `id=1 status=1` or do we have a *guarantee* that there will be at most one row?

Comment: @spencer7593 There is only one id=1 status=1 on table2

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes same id

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the tip! I've edited the question.

Comment: @Strawberry No - why do you say that? :-?

Comment: I'll get back to you on the 33rd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
select table1.id, table1.name,
    coalesce(table2_status1.status, table2_status2.status) as status,
    coalesce(table2_status1.date, table2_status2.date) as date,
    table3.value
from table1
left join table2 table2_status1 on table2_status1.id = table1.id and table2_status1.status = 1
left join table2 table2_status2 on table2_status2.id = table1.id and table2_status2.status = 2
join table3 on table3.id = table1.id
where (table2_status1.id is not null or table2_status2.id is not null);
```

Comment: `coalesce(table2_status1.status, table2_status2.status) as status, coalesce(table2_status1.date, table2_status2.date) as date` ? - yours is nicer,

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks. Good idea for coalesce, I didn't immediately think about it.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Haha alright. If there are other typos you should edit my answer, it'll be faster :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner getting error Unknown column 'table2_status1' in 'where clause' [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd2f090/1)

Comment: @Mazinfriki use the last version of the query (it has been edited).

Comment: @PatrickArtner 0 records found on my sample [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd2f090/2/0)

Comment: @Mazinfriki table3 is empty in your sample, which wasn't the case in your question. If table3 can indeed be empty, replace the last `join` by a `left join`. Also, you are mentioning the wrong person, I hope he doesn't mind.

Comment: @Strawberry The `where` clause is for the last requirement "If no one of those values are present in TABLE2 then skip that id from results". Since it's 2 left joins, it needs to check that at least one of them matched.

Comment: @rlanvin Fair enough - but is that actually any different to making the first join an inner join?

Comment: @Strawberry If the first join was an inner join, then when there is no matching row in table2 with "status=1" nothing would be returned. OP wants "Else if TABLE2.status =1 does **not exists** then look for status =2 and return ONLY that line of TABLE2". So it has to be a left join. If you have another approach in mind though, feel free to share.

Comment: No. It looks like you've covered it.

Answer (score 0):

Not performant, using subselects, works ( but rlanvins https://stackoverflow.com/a/48235077/7505395 is nicer) :

A,B,C instead of First, Second, ...

```
select 
    TABLE1.name,

    case 
      when exists( select 1 from table2 where id = table1.id and status = 1)
        then 1
      when exists( select 1 from table2 where id = table1.id and status = 2)
        then 2 
    end as T2status,

    case 
      when exists( select 1 from table2 where id = table1.id and status = 1)
        then ( select date from table2 where id = table1.id and status = 1)
      when exists( select 1 from table2 where id = table1.id and status = 2)
        then ( select date from table2 where id = table1.id and status = 2)
    end as T2date,

    TABLE3.value
from table1
join table3 on table1.id = table3.id
where     
    exists( select 1 from table2 where id = table1.id and status = 1)
    or exists( select 1 from table2 where id = table1.id and status = 2)
```

**Output**

```
Name    T2status    T2date  value
A       1           '.11..' 34 
C       1           '.31..' 17
```

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1  (`id` int, `name` varchar(3));

INSERT INTO Table1   (`id`, `name`)
VALUES   (1, 'A'),  (2, 'B'),   (3, 'C');


CREATE TABLE Table2   (`id` int, `status` int, `date` varchar(9));

INSERT INTO Table2  (`id`, `status`, `date`)
VALUES   (1, 1, '''.11..'''),  (1, 2, '''.12..'''),   (1, 3, '''.13..'''),
         (2, 3, '''.23..'''),  (3, 1, '''.31..'''),   (3, 3, '''.33..''')
;


CREATE TABLE Table3  (`id` int, `value` int);

INSERT INTO Table3   (`id`, `value`)
VALUES     (1, 34),  (2, 22),  (3, 17);
```